# Vectorize row-level matching operation in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame of basketball play-by-play data of the following format (simplified):

```
     Shooter       h1         h2        h3           h4          h5  th1  th2  th3  th4  th5  
0  K. Irving  K. Love  K. Irving  L. James  T. Thompson  D. Liggins  0.5  1.4  5.3  4.8  4.3  
1    K. Love  K. Love  K. Irving  L. James  T. Thompson  D. Liggins  0.6  1.5  5.4  4.9  4.4  
2   L. James  K. Love  K. Irving  L. James  T. Thompson  D. Liggins  0.7  1.6  5.5  5.0  4.5
```

where 'th1' corresponds to the amount of time the player in 'h1' has played in the game up until that play. I am hoping to extract the amount of time each shooter has played in the game at the time of their shot by matching Shooter to the appropriate 'h' column, and then extracting the corresponding 'th' value. Basically:

```
     Shooter  TimeInGame
0  K. Irving  1.4
1    K. Love  0.6
2   L. James  5.5
```

I have done this in a rudimentary fashion (df.iterrows()), but was hoping to vectorize this operation so I could run through lots of data quickly. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Are the `h` columns always constant strings, e.g. `h1` always `K. Love`?

Comment: There's the occasional np.nan currently but those could be dropped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#Get all columns starting with 'h' and compare them with 'Shooter'
m = df[df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('h')]].eq(df.Shooter,0)

#Get all columns starting with 'th' and extract the values where m is True
time_in_game = df[df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('th')]]\
              .values[range(len(df)), np.where(m)[1]]

pd.DataFrame({"Shooter": df["Shooter"], "TimeInGame": time_in_game})
```

**Output**

```
     Shooter  TimeInGame
0  K. Irving         1.4
1    K. Love         0.6
2   L. James         5.5
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a straightforward way to do it. So my workaround is:

```
import pandas as pd
mask = df[["h1","h2","h3","h4","h5"]].eq(df["Shooter"],axis=0)
```

mask:

```
h1      h2      h3      h4      h5
False   True    False   False   False
True    False   False   False   False
False   False   True    False   False
```

Then find the time of each player:

```
times = df[["th1","th2","th3","th4","th5"]].values[mask.values].flatten()
```

Finally, create a new DataFrame:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "Shooter": df["Shooter"],
    "TimeInGame": times
})
```

My steps simply:

1. Compare h1...h5 columns to Shooter column.
2. Using the previous comparison find the time value in each th1..th5 columns.
3. Create new DataFrame.